# Finding the position of an element in a simple array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say we have this array:

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 45 [2] => 23 )
```

How can I determine the position of element '45' in this array?

I'm using PHP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Google to the rescue: [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 58):

Use [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) to get the key to a value:

```
$key = array_search(45, $arr);
```

And if you want to get its position in the array, you can search for the index of the key in the array of keys:

```
$offset = array_search($key, array_keys($arr));
```

So with an array like the following you will still get `1` as result:

```
$arr = array('foo' => 10, 'bar' => 45, 'baz' => 23);
```

Comment: I know this answer is old and maybe that's the reason, but with PHP 7.0 with that array you'll get `bar`, not `1`.