# Get unknown word that follows a specific word

Tags: php, regex, string, substring, text-extraction

I need to extract an unknown word that immediately follows a word then a comma.
More preceisely, I want to get the word that comes after `post` followed by a comma then a space.

Sample string 1:

```
admin wrote a new post, FIRE 2 days, 2 hours ago
```

Sample string 2:

```
admin posted an update 2 days, 3 hours ago
```

Only the first sample string qualifies and the word `FIRE` should be returned.

Comment: ok i used $c = strstr($title, "post,"); // gets text after post, but still it outputs `post, fire` how to remove the `post,`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Regular Expression

```
$string="admin wrote a new post, FIRE 2 days, 2 hours ago";
$result=preg_split('/post,/',$string);
if(count($result)>1){
$result_split=explode(' ',$result[1]);
print_r($result_split[1]);
}
```

This one outputs
  FIRE

[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GSLTiU)

Another way

```
$string="admin wrote a new post, FIRE 2 days, 2 hours ago";
$result=preg_match_all('/(?<=(post,))(\s\w*)/',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WMORqy)

Comment: There is no reason to perform multiple string splits to extract a single substring.  `preg_match_all()` is also unwarranted.

Answer (score 4):

Just use explode() method, locate the position of the word post, and extract the next word.

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);

foreach( $pieces as $key => $value )
{
if($pieces[$key] == 'post' )
{
echo $pieces[$key+1];
break;
}
}
```

or, the expert method:

```
echo $pieces[array_search('post', $pieces)+1];
```

Comment: The "expert method" should not be used by anyone.  It is not "false safe" and will return unexpected results when the needle is not found.

Comment: This advice will fail because neither input string provided by the asker will contain `post` after exploding on spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression for this.

```
$string="admin wrote a new post, FIRE 2 days, 2 hours ago";
preg_match('/(?<=post, )\S+/i', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the word that immediately follows "post"-comma-space, is a task best left to a regular expression.

Use `\b` before `post` (and the comma after) in the pattern to ensure that only the whole word "post" is matched.

Use `\K` to restart the full string match -- avoiding a lookbehind will improve pattern efficiency.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BT8KT))

```
if (preg_match('/\bpost, \K\S+/', $string, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Or

```
$string = preg_replace('/.*\bpost, (\S+).*/', '$1', $string, 1, $count);
if ($count) {
    echo $string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- split the string and put into array
- get index of "post"
- get the value of the array in position index+1

Comment: get the position how? like i told him? good steps suggestion, but no code; you should get a -1

Comment: Do not look for readily cooked meal. Make some effort to cook your meal. Other can provide only some ingredients, not ready meal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804354/finding-the-position-of-an-element-in-a-simple-array

Comment: This advice will result in false positive matching since the alternative input string also contains `post`. `admin posted an update 2 days, 3 hours ago`