# Get position of element in array created through mysql search - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I search a database that returns a bunch of values. These values are stored into an array called `$result_array`. I then want to find the position of an element within that array. Here is my current code

```
public function cardPosition($cid, $did) {

   $query  = "SELECT cid FROM card WHERE did = '$did' ORDER BY id ASC";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $result_array = array();

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $result_array[] = $row;
   }

   while ($correct_cid = current($result_array)) {
      if ($correct_cid == $cid) {
         $cardPosition = key($result_array);
      }
      next($result_array);
   }

   return $cardPosition;
}
```

I use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` because I want to assign every element a key value. I then use the second while loop to search for the element in the array that is the `$correct_cid` value. I then assign the value of the key to `$cardPosition` but when I `return $cardPosition` I get nothing. How can I get the position of the element within the array?

**Update**

I have used

```
$position = array_search($cid, $result_array);
```

but still get nothing as a result.

I know my query works because I ran

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

and I get the correct number of rows.

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding the position of an element in a simple array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3804354/3623027)

Comment: @SO-user I have tried that answer but it does not seem to work for me I use `$position = array_search($cid, $result_array);` and still does not work.

Comment: post the array stored in `$result_array`

Comment: do `print_r($result_array);` before `return $cardPosition;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find the position of array with `array_search()` function. suppose we have an array.

```
$a = array(
    'blue' => 'nice',
    'car' => 'fast',
    'number' => 'none'
);

echo array_search("car",array_keys($a));
```

Comment: I used `$cardPosition = array_search($cid, array_keys($result_array));` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: welcome. @Gary Johnson

Answer (score 0):

```
$position = array_search("search_text", $result_array);
```

Comment: I have tried this using `$position = array_search($cid, $result_array);` but still get nothing for a response.